# ListView AfterLabelEdit Firing Twice

Tags: c#, .net, listview, event-handling

I am developing a MySQL editor in C#, and I made it so you can rename databases by double-clicking the name. For some reason though, **AfterLabelEdit** is executed twice if I try to rename an already renamed section.

---

**Example**

---

I have a database named 'test_db'. After I double click it, it renames perfectly and updates the name server-side. But the second time I try to rename the database, it executes the AfterLabelEdit event twice, causing the SQL database to try renaming the database to itself, therefore throwing an error. Even worse, it then executes the remaining code, which in turn drops the database completely.

---

**The Code**

---

```
private void ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem selecteditem_ = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        originaldbname_ = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        selecteditem_.BeginEdit();
        listView1.AfterLabelEdit += ListView1_AfterLabelEdit;
    }
```

And here is the event itself (ommited) :

```
private void ListView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand rename_db = new MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE `" + e.Label + "`; ", dbconnect);
        try
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            reader = rename_db.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Rename failed. Maybe you already have a database named " + e.Label + "?");
        }
        if (treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[originaldbname_].Nodes.Count == 0)
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            rename_db.CommandText = "DROP DATABASE `" + originaldbname_ + "`";
            reader = rename_db.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Close();
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[originaldbname_].Name = e.Label;
            originaldbname_ = e.Label;
        }
        else
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            for (int i = 0; i < treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[originaldbname_].Nodes.Count; i++)
            {
                string tablename_ = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[originaldbname_].Nodes[i].Name;
                rename_db.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE `" + originaldbname_ + "`." + tablename_ + " RENAME `" + e.Label + "`." + tablename_ + "";
            }
            reader = rename_db.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

            }
            reader.Close();
            rename_db.CommandText = "DROP DATABASE `" + originaldbname_ + "`";
            reader = rename_db.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Close();
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[originaldbname_].Name = e.Label;
            originaldbname_ = e.Label;
            treeView1.Update();
            listView1.Refresh();
            treeView1.Refresh();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the following line inside `ListView1_MouseDoubleClick` event handler, every time you double-click, a new event handler will be attached, you try to rename for the third time, you will see `AfterLabelEdit` fire thrice.

```
listView1.AfterLabelEdit += ListView1_AfterLabelEdit;
```

Move this line out of `ListView1_MouseDoubleClick` event handler, put it in the form constructor/form load/somewhere at the beginning of your code.

```
public Form1(){
    InitializeComponent();
    listView1.AfterLabelEdit += ListView1_AfterLabelEdit;
}
```

Comment: Correct! I will award the bounty as soon as StackOverflow allows me.

Answer (score 0):

Everything after your try/catch block in ListView1_AfterLabelEdit will always be executed regardless of the catch because you are not exiting after showing the MessageBox.  You need a return; in there to stop the rest of the code from firing.

Try this:

```
catch
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Rename failed. Maybe you already have a database named ?");
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time the list item is double clicked a new handler gets added to the `AfterLabelEdit` event.

For instance when an item is clicked for the first time the following line gets executed

```
listView1.AfterLabelEdit += ListView1_AfterLabelEdit;
```

So, now one event handler is attached to the event. When the item is clicked again another handler gets attached to the event. So the event is getting triggered twice. If you will double click the item again, the event will be fired thrice.

An easy fix is to remove the event handler (`listView1.AfterLabelEdit -= ListView1_AfterLabelEdit;`) before adding it like shown below.

```
private void ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem selecteditem_ = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
    originaldbname_ = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
    selecteditem_.BeginEdit();
    listView1.AfterLabelEdit -= ListView1_AfterLabelEdit;
    listView1.AfterLabelEdit += ListView1_AfterLabelEdit;
}
```